# VS 2013 Config File Missing in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, configuration-files, azure-cloud-services

I have created an Azure Cloud Service (call it **A**) in Visual Studio 2013, using Azure SDK v2.6.  The cloud service has a single role from project **B**, project **B** references project **C**, and project **C** references project **D**.  Project **D** includes a content file called `D.dll.config`.  I have verified that when I build, the file `D.dll.config` exists in `D\bin\Debug\`, `C\bin\Debug\`, and `B\bin\Debug\`.  However, when I run **A** in both the emulator and on Azure, my config file is absent.

On my local machine, this directory is `A\csx\Debug\roles\B\approot\`.  Does anyone know how to get the configuration file to be included with my cloud service?  A brief explanation as to why it is not being included to begin with would also be appreciated.

Comment: I found an approach that works, as documented [here on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2012/06/08/add-files-to-your-windows-azure-package-using-role-content-folders.aspx).  However, if I do that then 1) I have to manually include all content files that all referenced projects need, and 2) I have to maintain a copy of the file in the cloud service directory structure.  Both of these issues are maintenance nightmares, so this solution is inadequate.

Comment: [This question/answer on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/05906f06-1164-441f-982a-c71c1909defe/include-custom-files-in-cloud-package-without-explicit-references-from-visual-studio?forum=windowsazuredevelopment) suggests there is a way to do this that would resolve the second issue I brought up in my previous comment, but I couldn't get that solution to work on Azure v2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker stumbled across a solution while he was creating a new cloud service.  If I add a reference from project **B** (the one that contains the cloud service role) to project **D** (the one that contains the config file as content), then `D.dll.config` is included in the approot directory in my emulator, as well as in Azure.

This solution is still not ideal, as I have to add an explicit reference to all dll's with content.  However, it is the best solution that I know of thus far.